Do the sentences provided mean the same thing?
"They have seven months to show they've improved. If they don't improve in these seven months, they'll be fired."
Does the sentence below mean the same as the quote above? If not, what does the sentence below mean?
They have seven months to show improvement before they're fired.

This isn't a proofreading service, but if it were, I'd say that you could remove the ambiguity in the second sentence by replacing "before" with "or", as in, "They have seven months to show improvement or they'll be fired"

Whoever wrote the second sentence should be fired.

Yes, the first pair of sentences expands and explains the meaning of "They have seven months to show improvement before they're fired" in a clear way. This is only because of this context and situation. We understand that there's a relationship between showing improvement and being fired, and that it might be common to avoid being fired by showing improvement. So in the one-sentence version, we understand that there's a cause-and-effect situation, as explained more clearly in the two sentence version.
However, this doesn't come just from this pattern of grammar. If we said "They have five minutes to finish eating before the bus leaves," the bus leaving won't be affected in any way by the eating.
